# JavaScript/Jquery - Retrieving data in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, so suppose I have the following function that I use to append a new row into a table. Could someone please give some suggestions how I would be able to get the value of the textarea boxes or check whether each checkbox is checked on the last row that I add to the table? I'm trying to use getElementByName() but a bit unsure on how to get the data on the specific row I want. The table is part of a jsp page. Thanks lots!!!

```
function generateNewRow(id){
        var tr = "<tr>";

        tr += "<td><input name='id' type='hidden' value='" + id + "' />";
        tr += "<textarea name='a' style='width: 98%; height:40px'></textarea></td>";
        tr += "<td>";
        tr += "<input type='checkbox' name='b' value='" + id + "'/>B";
        tr += "<input type='checkbox' name='c' value='" + id + "'/>C";
        tr += "<input type='checkbox' name='d' value='" + id + "'/>D";
        tr += "<input type='checkbox' name='e' value='" + id + "'/>E<br/>";
        tr += "<input type='checkbox' name='f' value='" + id + "'/>F;
        tr += "</td>";

        tr += "<td><textarea name='g' style='width: 98%; height:40px'></textarea></td>";

        tr += "</tr>";

        $("#ProblemsGrid tbody").append(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the last row of the table you can use a selector like so:

```
$("#ProblemnsGris tbody tr:last");
```

For textarea and input values I would use `find` along with `each`:

```
$("#ProblemsGrid tr:last").find('input:checkbox').each(function(index, element){
    var value = $(element).is(':checked');
    alert(value);
});

$("#ProblemsGrid tr:last").find('textarea').each(function(index, element){
    var value = $(element).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dqryf/